# Nesting and combining annotations for DynamoDB is not working

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a fairly simple java object structure, with annotations, that is not working. It looks like this:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Job {

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "mapping")
    private Definition definition;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class Definition {
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "calculationMap")
    @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = AssignmentsConverter.class)
    private Map<String, Calculation> assignments;
}
```

The information in dynamo thus looks like this:

```
mapping: {
    calculationMap: {
        attribute1: "string representing Calculation",
        attribute2: "string representing Calculation"
    }
}
```

I'd thus expect my java Job object to look like this:

```
definition: {
    assignments: {
        attribute1: Calculation1,
        attribute2: Calculation2
    }
}
```

However, the annotations fail to deserialize the map properly. The converter code never gets called, and I end up with a Job object that has a Mapping, but the assignments field in Mapping is null. So basically it looks like this:

```
definition: {
    assignments: null
}
```

The converter itself is fairly simple, so I won't provide the code unless requested. However, it shouldn't be causing problem as it's not even being called.

The code was working fine before I added the `@DynamoDBAttribute` annotations and changed the name of the java fields. The names all match though, so I am worried it might have something to do with the interaction between the various annotations? I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had been pulling my hair out trying to solve this for hours, and it turned out it was a simple mistake on my part - I was looking at DynamoDB to see the data I was extracting, but at some point I had overwritten it with null and didn't refresh. By refreshing my view in DynamoDB I could see it was now null. I reset `calculationMap` to a valid value, and voila, it was working as expected.